Physical server with LED display on case, possibly programmable
Sometime in the 2000s I was in the server room of a customer site. This was still in the days of largely on-premise, not necessarily rack-mounted server boxes. A guy from their hardware vendor was waiting for something or other to complete, and amusing himself by playing what looked like a card game on an LCD or LED display on top of the server case.
Has anyone ever come across hardware with a display like that? It was probably a big name manufacturer, like Dell, Fujitsu or similar.

What did the display look like?  Was it a bitmapped display of a standard-ish resolution, or a smaller display such as might be used to display hardware status?  How big was it?  Was it monochrome, and if so, what color was it?

In the last largish server room I was in, servers had provision for VGA display, keyboard, mouse which were generally not connected; there were a handful of such devices around that could be hooked up to any server in need.

That would have been a separate device, probably in a 5 inch drive bay-- not part of the server.  A real user interface would be through a monitor. It also may have been a small portable monitor used for diag. Though I'm not surprised someone wrote a game for it. I've played games on communication network devices.

Did the display's resolution appear to be closer to this drive bay CRT or this built-in LCD??

It was a bitmapped mono LCD display built into the case as I remember it, I got the impression it would normally display hardware status.

On the front of the case, not really on top of it, as stated in the question?  Or some sort of flip-up screen as found in some HP laser printers these days?

I'm beginning to suspect it was a Dell tower with an IDRAC LCD display - apparently you could get these on the towers as well as the rack servers.
